# Debugging stack trace

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

My application for windows phone uses Microsoft Ad SDK and recently I have noticed a lot of crashes in the application which I feel has something to do with the Ad SDK/control. The stack trace provided by the App Hub for the app can be accessed from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4975610/stacktrace.txt).

Any idea what is causing the crash?

Comment: Which version of the Microsoft Ad SDK are you using?  Some versions prior to November 2011 had a bug which caused occasional crashes.

Comment: The dll version number is 5.2.819.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the stack trace I think you have the same problem that this guy had:
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Handling-AdControl-Fetching-Exception

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue in the debugger so I am not sure if the latest update to the Ad sdk fixed this issue or not. I was earlier using the older version

Comment: Thanks! a comment to this post, which asked me to update to the latest version of the SDK, fixed the issue :)